# Why are matrices indexed by row first?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am wondering is there some greater thought behind indexing matrices in form `(row, column)`, or is it just something that someone did, and everybody else followed?

When I'm looking at the matrix, I find it easiest to imagine it as numbers laid out in 2D grid. From my previous education I usually follow `(x,y)` order, and it seems like in many other areas we usually deal with `x` before `y`. When I'm thinking ${A_{3 1}}$, I'd think x = 3, y = 1, and therefore get 3rd column and 1st row. This would be wrong - I need to do otherwise(y's first).

Why so?

Comment: You could ask over at [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would say the same thing about 'Why are most scripts written from left to right' ?.  Of course there are some scripts written right to left in vertical columns

Comment: I suspect it comes from general European practice of reading and writing text top line to bottom line and left to right on each line.  So the top row is "first row" , then each entry runs in consecutive columns before advancing to the next row down.  The real number line runs left to right for a similar "reason".  These are just conventions arrived at by contigencies of historical practice; someone makes a choice that eventually "sticks" with later practitioners.  There aren't "logical" arguments for many such practices.

Comment: On thinking about it a little more in regard to your grid, one could argue that the $ \ x-$ axis is running downward, which puts the $ \ y-$ axis running left-to-right, and the entries of the matrix given as (row, column) are then consistent with the practice for ordered pairs.  But this could be seen as justification after the fact.  Other ways could have been chosen -- this is the one that's come down to us (and once _that_ happens, it can be really _tough_ to get people to change the convention).

Comment: See [Earliest Uses of Symbols for Matrices and Vectors](http://jeff560.tripod.com/matrices.html). About the coefficients $a_{ij}$ of a system of linear equations, Leibniz writes (badly translated by me): "...the first [index] denotes of which equation it is, the second denotes to which variable it applies." Vandermonde and Laplace do something similar. Evidently people consider the equation numbers to be more important than the variable numbers.

Comment: If you've got an answer, please post it as an answer - not as a comment. I'm asking because I'm curious, but others might appreciate having a accepted answer, if they got the same question.
@Lovsovs - didn't know about this site, lol. I could have, but cross-posting is wrong, so I'd expect moderator to migrate my question, if he thinks that's the right thing to do.

Comment: I think the programming language IDL (similar to Matlab) indexes matrices the way you suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I believe that the true reason is purely historical, here’s a possible explanation for why the common notation might be more natural, and it boils down to the following facts:

1. We like to think of the composition $g ∘ f$ of maps $f \colon X → Y$, $g \colon Y → Z$ as “$g$ after $f$” not the other way around (viz. to ensure that “$(g∘f)(x) = g(f(x))$” holds, which is intuitive).
2. We like to think of matrices as linear maps in a “covariant way”.
3. We like to think of vectors as columns (to avoid wasting precious horizontal space (because we write from left to right, not from top to bottom)).
4. We like to cancel stuff out in the middle rather than outside, because that sticks better in my (our?) memory.

So let $R$ be a ring (or a field, take $R = ℚ$ in need) and read on.

In linear Algebra, we often use matrices $A ∈ \operatorname{Mat}_{m×n}(R)$ as maps that are given by multiplication
$$f_A \colon R^n → R^m,~x ↦ Ax,$$
for which we actually need to think of vectors in $R^n$ and $R^m$ as columns.

Now, we *could* also think of them as maps
$$f_A^{op} \colon R^m → R^n,~x ↦ xA,$$
but then we would

- lose the nice “covariant” identity $f_A∘f_B = f_{AB}$ (and would end up instead with the “contravariant” identity $f_B^{op}∘f_A^{op} = f_{AB}^{op}$), and
- need to think of $R^m$ and $R^n$ as rows rather than columns *or*
- redefine the matrix product to multiply columns of the first matrix onto rows of the second (instead of rows of the first onto columns of the second).

While the last two points might not be an issue, the first one is for many people. So we favor the interpretation $f_A$ over the interpretation $f_A^{op}$.

Okay, so now if you write out a product of a matrix by a vector, you really want to preserve horizontal space, so you rather think of the vector as being a column. We also would like to consider this product to be a special case of a general matrix product, considering vectors as special matrices.

This forces us to multiply matrices by the scheme “dot product of rows of the first matrix by columns of the second matrix”. In particular, the number of rows of a product is determined by its first factor, the number of columns by its second factor.

Now, if we were to annotate by $(j,i)$ the entry at the $j$-th column and $i$-th row of a matrix, the definition of the matrix product
$$(c_{ji})_{n×m} = (a_{ki})_{q×m}·(b_{jk})_{n×q}$$
would be
$$c_{ji} = \sum_{k=1}^q a_{ki}·b_{jk},$$
so you wouldn’t be able to memorize it as “the middle index is cancelling out” which, to me, sounds way more natural than “the outer indices are cancelling out”.

Of course, you sacrifice the naturality of having the two-dimensional grid, reminiscent of the cartesian plane, as you suggested. But since we are already writing matrices top-left to bottom-right (because that’s the way we write) as others already pointed out in the comments, you can’t really think of a matrix in the same way as the cartesian plane anyway, so why try to force it? The way it is, it at least preserves the mathematical positive orientation and if you tilt your head by $-π/2$, you again have your cartesian plane!

Comment: Actually, I am not anymore certain that this is a correct argument. I’ll think about it and get back to this in the unforeseeable future.

Comment: "Actually, I am not anymore certain that this is a correct argument" - What argument are you referring to?

Comment: @Filippo It’s an old answer, I can’t remember what exactly I was thinking back then. All I can say is that, after reading my answer through again, I feel very convinced by my former self, so I’m not sure if there really was a problem with my reasoning.

Comment: "I feel very convinced by my former self" - That's great, lol. Thank you for your time and comment!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the historical reason, but this is how I understand it intuitively based on how vectors and matrices are used in modern mathematics and computer graphics.

Vectors are most commonly notated in column major (vertical) form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

When looking up matrix transformations for example, the overwhelming majority you find will be given using column vectors. For example, from wikipedia:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  x' \\
  y' \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
  \sin\theta &  \cos\theta \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since vectors are thought of as columns, it makes sense that you can just consider a matrix to be multiple column vectors together:

$$ \require{color}
\begin{bmatrix}
\colorbox{lightgreen}{$x_1$} & \colorbox{lightblue}{$x_2$} & \colorbox{yellow}{$x_3$} \\
\colorbox{lightgreen}{$y_1$} & \colorbox{lightblue}{$y_2$} & \colorbox{yellow}{$y_3$} \\
\colorbox{lightgreen}{$z_1$} & \colorbox{lightblue}{$z_2$} & \colorbox{yellow}{$z_3$} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In this way, the notation of M-by-N or Row-by-Column makes perfect sense. The dimensionality of the vectors (i.e 2D, 3D) is most important, the number of vectors is in the matrix is of secondary importance.

To illustrate:

$$ \require{color}
\begin{bmatrix}
\colorbox{lightgreen}{$x_1$} & \colorbox{lightblue}{$x_2$} & \colorbox{yellow}{$x_3$} \\
\colorbox{lightgreen}{$y_1$} & \colorbox{lightblue}{$y_2$} & \colorbox{yellow}{$y_3$} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

These are **2D** vectors and we have **3** of them, therefore this is a $2 \times 3$ matrix.

$$ \require{color}
\begin{bmatrix}
\colorbox{lightgreen}{$x_1$} & \colorbox{lightblue}{$x_2$} & \colorbox{yellow}{$x_3$} & \colorbox{orange}{$x_4$} & \colorbox{pink}{$x_5$} \\
\colorbox{lightgreen}{$y_1$} & \colorbox{lightblue}{$y_2$} & \colorbox{yellow}{$y_3$} & \colorbox{orange}{$y_4$} & \colorbox{pink}{$y_5$} \\
\colorbox{lightgreen}{$z_1$} & \colorbox{lightblue}{$z_2$} & \colorbox{yellow}{$z_3$} & \colorbox{orange}{$z_4$} & \colorbox{pink}{$z_5$} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

These are **3D** vectors and we have **5** of them, therefore this is a $3 \times 5$ matrix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the "original" reason goes back much further in time and is intuitive and based on hierarchy of information. For example, if I ask someone where a word is on a page, it is much more intuitive to tell me to go to line fifteen and look at word six, than it is to tell me to look at word six and then go down to line fifteen. We naturally specify the line (i.e. the row) and then the column or word, as does the editor I'm writing this in.

We naturally generate information with a single row and then get more rows as we write more lines. When we fill a page we add pages, giving depth and a third dimension. Then we have a book, then a shelf of books and then a section in a library, etc. It is far more natural to tell someone to go to "Mathematics", shelf 3, book 17, page 33, line 7, word 5, than it is to say to go to word 5, then line 7, then page 33, then book 17, then shelf 3, in the "Mathematics" section.

Likewise, with a video, you would specify the frame number before saying which pixel to read.

We give the information in the natural hierarchy of information and order we need it. The "new" dimension becomes the first dimension and the others get shuffled along but maintaining their order. This used to really catch me out when I was learning Matlab some time ago and addressing matrices, where the dimensions are numbered and accessed like `my_array(dim3, dim2, dim1)` but it makes sense.

For 2D graphs, we state the x-coordinate before the y-coordinate. I suspect that is because we think of things happening from left to right (e.g. time), just like we progress through the world horizontally rather than vertically, so we go to that point and then enter the information on the graph. And when we get a third dimension, that is height or depth, but we usually can't control that: I can't say go to an altitude of 200 m and then move 500 m to the left, where you will then find yourself standing on a hill. Or go to (x, y) and dig a hole z deep.

So, I think it is all based on our experience of the world and how we interact with it, rather than an actual mathematical reason.